# What exactly do the two "Do not process the legacy run list" group policy settings do?

Tags: windows, group-policy

The two "Do not process the legacy run list" settings appear under Computer Configuration -> Polices -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Logon and under User Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Logon respectively.

The documentation for these settings is confusing (i.e., wrong); what exactly do these two settings do, and how do they interact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual behaviour (as observed in Windows 7 x64 SP1) is quite simple and intuitive:

- The Computer Configuration setting disables the Run list that is found in this registry key:

  `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`
- The User Configuration setting disables the Run list that is found in this registry key:

  `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`

Contrary to the documentation, the settings do not interact; configuring the computer setting does not affect the behaviour of the user setting.